# Read Unicode UTF-32 file into wstring

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode

For UTF-16, we can read and convert it to `wchar` at the same time. For example,

```
std::wifstream* file = new std::wifstream(name, ifstream::binary);
locale lo = locale(file->getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>);
file->imbue(lo);
```

How could I do the same for UTF-32 input?

Comment: from [std::codecvt_utf16](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16), you can use `std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::u32string conversion to/from std::string and std::u16string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302506/stdu32string-conversion-to-from-stdstring-and-stdu16string)

Comment: @danh, perhaps not quite a duplicate - though I'm guessing you can just substitute `std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t>` into the `imbue()`?  (I don't really know; I only ever need UTF-8 myself)

Comment: Is this in Windows? What compiler/version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a classic C++ pattern of allocating `wifstream` on the stack instead of the heap (`new`):

> ```
> std::wifstream* file = new std::wifstream(name, ifstream::binary);
> ```

```
std::wifstream file(name, ifstream::binary);
```

For the codecvt part, I'd try with `std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t>`.

**P.S.** Note that `wchar_t` can have *different* sizes (16 bits, 32 bits) on different platforms. So it may be better for you to use `std::u16string` for UTF-16 and `std::u32string` for UTF-32.

Comment: The codecvt std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t> doesn't work. I think I need something like std::codecvt_utf32, which doesn't exist. Can I create my own? Thanks.